# ActiveRecord 3.2 vs. 3.0 Uniq Method Ignored in Join Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

About two weeks ago I updated my Rails app from 3.0 to 3.2 (just in time for 4! Sigh.). Anyway, I've just noticed something odd — a query that returned correctly-ordered results in the old version is returning consistently-incorrect results in 3.2.

Here's the query:

```
@sessions = user.email_sessions.joins(:email_stats)
            .where('email_stats.event_type = "open"')
            .order('email_stats.created_at DESC')
            .uniq
```

This query in Rails 3.2 returns these timestamps:

```
2013-06-18 12:02:05 -0400
2013-06-18 11:24:22 -0400
2013-06-18 10:41:52 -0400
2013-06-18 12:09:42 -0400
2013-06-18 10:02:26 -0400
2013-06-18 10:24:40 -0400
2013-06-18 08:59:19 -0400
2013-06-18 08:59:19 -0400
2013-06-18 08:51:39 -0400
2013-06-14 15:47:28 -0400
```

Whereas in 3.0, I get this:

```
2013-06-18 12:09:42 -0400
2013-06-18 12:03:23 -0400
2013-06-18 12:02:05 -0400
2013-06-18 11:24:22 -0400
2013-06-18 10:41:52 -0400
2013-06-18 10:24:40 -0400
2013-06-18 10:02:26 -0400
2013-06-18 08:59:19 -0400
2013-06-18 08:59:19 -0400
2013-06-18 08:51:39 -0400
```

That's good! Rails 3.2 is bad! Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

**Update:** It just occurred to me to check Rails 3.1, which I slid through briefly on my way to 3.2. I checked out the latest commit of that branch, and the dates are good there. It's only on 3.2 that this problem occurs.

**Update 2:** Thanks to Dhurv's question below, I've gotten the raw SQL being generated in both versions of Rails. I used the .to_sql method on the first, and I pulled the latter from the log. **The difference: the .uniq method is only there in 3.2** Why?

Rails 3.2

> SELECT DISTINCT `email_sessions`.* FROM `email_sessions` INNER JOIN `email_stats` ON `email_stats`.`email_session_id` = `email_sessions`.`id` WHERE `email_sessions`.`user_id` = 374 AND (email_stats.event_type = "open") ORDER BY email_stats.created_at DESC

Rails 3.0

> SELECT `email_sessions`.* FROM `email_sessions` INNER JOIN `email_stats` ON `email_stats`.`email_session_id` = `email_sessions`.`id` WHERE (`email_sessions`.user_id = 374) AND (email_stats.event_type = "open") ORDER BY email_stats.created_at DESC

Comment: Does the raw sql generated by rails differ from 3.0 to 3.2? You can tack on a '.to_sql' to the end of your query to find out.

Comment: @Dhurv -- good idea, but the to_sql method doesn't exist in Rails 3.0 to compare it to! However, I got the SQL output from the log. There are differences, which I'll add to in my question above.